# Why is the $n$-dimensional Lebesgue measure by default not complete?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Since the Lebesgue measure is complete, why is the product of Lebesgue measures not necessarily complete? Would anyone be able to provide some intuition or an example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $\mu$ be the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$.  The product measure $\mu \times \mu$ is defined on the $\sigma$-algebra generated by rectangles of the form $A \times B$ where both $A$ and $B$ are Lebesgue measurable subsets of $\mathbb{R}$.

Now suppose that $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ has measure $0$, and $B \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is measurable.  Then $(\mu \times \mu)(A \times B) = 0$, but an arbitrary subset of $A \times B$ does not have to be in the $\sigma$-algebra generated by measurable rectangles.

For a concrete example, consider the case when $A = \{0\}$ and $B = [0, 1]$.  Let $V \subseteq [0, 1]$ be the Vitali set (or any other non-measurable set you like).  Then $(\mu \times \mu)(A \times B) = (\mu \times \mu)(\{0\} \times [0, 1]) = 0$, and $\{0\} \times V \subseteq \{0\} \times [0, 1]$, but $\{0\} \times V$ is not in the $\sigma$-algebra generated by measurable rectangles.

By the way, I think it's more common to use the phrase "$2$-dimensional Lebesgue measure" to refer to the completion of $\mu \times \mu$, rather than to mean $\mu \times \mu$ itself.  With that naming convention, $n$-dimensional Lebesgue measure *is* complete, by definition.